# Spring Boot 3 Graalvm Native JDBC cannot convert value of type 'java.sql.Timestamp' to required type 'java.time.Instant'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I implemented CRUD operations in Spring Boot. And everything works fine when I use `./gradlew bootRun`.

But when I run native image from `./gradlew clean nativeCompile` the operations which retrieve objects from DB are failing with:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: conversion to class java.time.Instant from timestamptz not supported
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getObject(PgResultSet.java:3874) ~[na:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getObject(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(JdbcUtils.java:230) ~[na:na]
...
```

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.sql.Timestamp' to required type 'java.time.Instant' for property 'createdOn': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:259)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:589)
```

Example `findById` operation:

```
  public Optional<ClientDto> findById(String tenantId, UUID id) {
    List<ClientDto> result =
        db.query(
            "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE tenant_id = ? AND id = ?",
            DataClassRowMapper.newInstance(ClientDto.class),
            tenantId,
            id);
    return result.size() == 1 ? Optional.ofNullable(result.get(0)) : Optional.empty();
  }
```

`ClientDto`:

```
 public record ClientDto(
    UUID id,
    String tenantId,
    String name,
    String description,
    Instant createdOn,
    Instant modifiedOn) {
 }
```

I believe that some type converters are not initialized or not being found in the native image of my app, but I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to change `DataClassRowMapper` to `BeanPropertyRowMapper` and use normal `class` instead of java `record`, but result was the same.

I also tried to introduce my custom converter from `sql.Timestamp` to `time.Instant`, but it didn't work either.

When I change my repository implementation to use `ListCRUDRepository` - it works.

When using `RowMapper` instead of `DataClassRowMapper` - it works.

I would like to use `DataClassRowMapper`, but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: can you share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example